# is there any way to see the log of real device of ios or debugging iap in emulator in flutter app

Tags: ios

Now I am deveoping in app purchase in iOS using flutter, but the in app purchase did not support debugging on simulator, so I have to package my app and install in real device and test in app purchase, but the problem is the package take me so much time. And I could not see the log and code workflow so I did not know where is going wrong. So I have to tweak my code and package the apk file(the ci may take me hours) again and again. It make me crazy, is it possible to show the log or let me debbuging in simulator when develop in app purchase in iOS?

how to see the log? I write a rest api and send log info to the server side.

```
static Future<void> logger(String restLog) async {
    RestLogModel restLogModel = RestLogModel();
    restLogModel.message = restLog;
      Map jsonMap = restLogModel.toMap();
      try {
        final response = await RestClient.postHttp( "/post/logger/v1/log", jsonMap);
        if (response.statusCode == 200 &&
            response.data["statusCode"] == "200") {
          Map channelResult = response.data["result"];
          if (channelResult != null) {
            // Pay attention: channelResult would be null sometimes
            String jsonContent = JsonEncoder().convert(channelResult);
          }
        } else {
          AppLogHandler.logError(RestApiError('Item failed to fetch.'),
              JsonEncoder().convert(response));
        }
      } on Exception catch (e) {
        
      }
  }
```

It works fine. But every time I change the code, I have to repackage the code and install in real device to verify the change, is there anyway to make it easy? like debugging in app purchase in an emulator?

Answer (score 1):

You can use OS Logs to capture the log statements in the MAC Console app and filter the logs by your category

> import os.log
>
> extension OSLog {
> private static var subsystem = Bundle.main.bundleIdentifier!
> /// Logs the view cycles like viewDidLoad.
> static let viewCycle = OSLog(subsystem: subsystem, category: "viewcycle") }

Comment: I am using flutter, are you sure your code works in fluuter? @Ram